# Clarification on Cost of SQL query in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g

I have written a query for which I am confused on cost calculation.

The cost of below query is coming ~1000.

```
.........FIRST PART OF QUERY
And status = 'AB'
.........REMAINING PART OF QUERY
```

When I change the same above query as below:

```
.........FIRST PART OF QUERY
AND status = 'PQR'
.........REMAINING PART OF QUERY
```

Now the cost of same query is coming as ~50000. The only change is in the value of condition. There is no other difference in both the queries. (index is created on status column)

So my question is, The cost of query is dependent on the condition value as well or why there is huge change in the cost of these two queries.

Comment: Based on the statistics of the table Oracle assumes that there are much more rows with `status = 'PQR'` than for the other value.

Comment: So you mean to say the cost is dependent on the value(AB/PQR) of condition as well...!

Comment: Why shouldn't it? If you have population indexed by age, that index will be much more useful (selective) if you are looking for 100-year old people than if you are looking for 15-year olds.

Comment: As mentioned @a_horse_with_no_name, the statistic is the main factor to choose use index or not (index seek vs clustered index scan). Anyway. Imagine, you have 1 record that matches `status = 'AB'` and a million records that matches `status = 'PQR'` in table with ten million records. Which costs will be in this case?

Comment: Got it. Due to huge no records, the cost was coming too high.